# Can I use MySql with SignalR?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, signalr

Goodmorning,
is there anyone that has already developed something about how to insert, update or select chat conversation in asp.net with MySql database?
I found SqlDependency class open source, then MySqlDependency that is like 100$ each year.
Still nothing open source for Mysql db?
I tried to develop something, my idea was just, insert or update the db when the client leave or change the page but there is nothing about event on change url domain with javascript.
I never thought that it could be so difficult to develop a chat.

Can some good people help posting some code about this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

it's actually very easy if you get the concept. you can check the video from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Fxm_54j-h8 and also you can find the code in the description.

although it's written on Entity Framework core with SQL server provider. you can just change the provider for MySQL and it'll work.

Comment: I just see right now that you are the author, nice to meet you, I have sent to you an email at asif0531@live.com, thank you very much

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Comment: based on Asif Rahman GitHub repository, I forked and tailored it for .net 6 and MySQL:

Here it is
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700768/1655837

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, based on [Asif Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744253/asif-rahman) GitHub [repository](https://github.com/MicroAsif/signalR101), I forked and tailored it for **.net 6** and **MySQL**:

[Here it is](https://github.com/AhmedSuror/signalR101)